# JBoss AS6 how to use context.lookup with security

Tags: security, jboss6.x

I've just upgraded my application from JBoss 3 to Jboss 6.
I'm trying to use a contex lookup to get a MBeanServerConnection as you can see:

```
private MBeanServerConnection getAdapter() throws NamingException{
        String [] creds = getUserCreds();
        String username = creds[0];
        String pwd      = creds[1];
        setPrincipal(new SimplePrincipal(username));
        setCredential(pwd.toCharArray());
        return (MBeanServerConnection) context.lookup("jmx/invoker/RMIAdaptor");
```

when I enable security in the c:\App\EJBContainer\server\ default\deploy\jmx-jboss-beans.xml by uncommenting the following line:
    secure
after defining the application-policy in c:\App\EJBContainer\server\default\conf\login-config.xml,
I get an exception saying I didn't provide user/password: 
java.lang.SecurityException: JMXConnectorAuthenticator requires userid/password credentials to be passed in.
can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.
Boaz.